# I'm having a bit of difficulty with fscanf and 2D arrays.

Tags: c

So lets say I have to read in the text

Bob 5 5 5

Sam 4 4 4

or

2 2 2 Joe

1 1 1 Larry

using a separate 2D array for the numbers and other for the names. How would I go about doing it?

I thought about using at least for the first case

```
char reading;
int test[MAX][LEN];//where max is some #define, does not matter 
while (i<MAX && reading = fgetc(foo) !=EOF ){
   if (j<LEN && reading != '\n){
      fscanf(foo, "%d", test[i][j]);//i'm really not sure. sorry :( 
      j++;
   }
   i++; 
}
```

Is there where you would use stuff like %*c in fscanf also how do you check for the new line? 
I'm so very lost any help understanding the material would be appreciated.

Comment: Start with learning how [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) works. Until you get a grip on that function, I fear any explanation here will just add to your confusion.

Comment: `fscanf` needs an address of the variable being read.

Comment: so it needs &test[i][j]

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MAX 10
#define LEN 3

int main(void){
    int test[MAX][LEN]={0};
    char name[MAX][64];
    char linebuff[128];
    FILE *foo;
    int i,j,k;

    foo=fopen("data.txt", "r");

    for(i=0;i<MAX && NULL!=fgets(linebuff, sizeof(linebuff), foo);++i){
        char *p, *endp;
        j=0;
        for(p=linebuff;NULL!=(p=strtok(p, " \t\n"));p=NULL){
            int num;
            num=strtol(p, &endp, 10);
            if(*endp == '\0'){
                if(j<LEN)
                    test[i][j++]=num;
            } else {
                strcpy(name[i], p);//unnecessary?
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(foo);
    //check print
    for(j=0;j<i;++j){
        printf("%s ", name[j]);
        for(k=0;k<LEN;++k)
            printf("%d ", test[j][k]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry But I don't understand most of this. I have no idea what linebuffs or strtok are. can you keep this simple?

Comment: @user2388958 don't have a library reference?